# Passing Data from one form to another form in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am currently having problems trying to send data from one form to another form using a button. I have a program where by the client is requesting a new part for their vehicle. The user then applies online and when the part is approved, the user then enter the information into the system. The problem i have is that i am trying to send the relevant data from one form to another that form. Please assist

```
 <p>
        <?php
        if($model->status=="Approved")
        {
        echo Html::a('Insert into Parts', ['/parts/create?'.$model->lp], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ;
        }
        ?>

    </p>
```

https://ibb.co/c9rDKn

https://ibb.co/k56kX7

Please view the attached file. On the first image it has the information that is  saved into the database also on the top it has a button called insert into part. When the user click the button they are redirected to the send form to insert the part (that is the second image) but i want when the user click the button the information that is related to it is then transferred to the other form. sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your part controller in create method you should handle to scenario

**GET request**: here you will load the vehicle using id submitted using the button then you will populated needed fields in the form.

**POST request**: here you will validate your model before saving it and then you will show the view model page if things went well.

```
public function actionCreate($id){
  $vehicle = Vehicle::findOne($id);
  $part = new Part();
  //now we have both Vehicle and new part object 
  //based on your desgin if you want to duplicate both your will do this 
  $pary->lincense_plate = $vehicle->lincense_plate;
  //do it for all then the fields will have values if you use ActiveForm

  //better desgin to avoid duplication and have a relation one to many between vehicle and part
  //send both models and show vehicle data as disable field or span 

  //here we handel post case
  if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
    $part->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    if ($part->save())
      //render view page
      return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $part->id]);
  }
  return $this->render('create', [
            'vehicle' => $vehicle,
            'part' => $part,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Hello Mohd Almoar, Thanks for the response, sorry for the late response. What i wanted to achieved is that when the user click insert parts the license plate is automatically sent to the parts-form form, because in that form the user will continue to fill in the require information. This works excellent if the user didn't have to insert more information.

Comment: Yes as I explained in the answer send the vehicle id to the controller then create new part and fill the lincese number from the vehicle. And send the part model to the form usind render

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks a million mien. Such a small code can change an entire program.